# Refreshing jstree without tree 'flashing' in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a page with `jstree` in it. It's loading the tree content from the server in JSON format.

```
$("#" + this.treeComponentID).jstree({        
        plugins: ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "types"],
        themes: {
            theme: "classic"
        },
        json_data: {
            "ajax": {
                "url": this.dataLoadURL
            }
        },
        ui: {
            select_limit: 1
        }
    });
```

Every 20s I call

```
 $('#tree').jstree("refresh", -1);
```

to refresh the tree since the content might change on backend. This all works fine except I got a ~200ms flash of the component in Chrome. This is very annoying if you look on the page and it flashes every 20s.

So I was wondering whether there is some way to avoid this flash. What is even more strange is that IE8 doesn't flash. It just repaint the tree silently and smoothly.

I'm using the jsTree 1.0-rc3 which is presented on the jstree webpages in demos.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a refresh, would it help to do a redraw?

```
$('#tree').jstree("redraw");
```